# Error reports "Residual sum squares is 0" in ANOVA analysis in R

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, anova

I have a problem with calculating ANOVA with my data in R. The R reports an error when I run ANOVA, it shows"Residual sum squares is 0". How can I solve this problem?
By the way, my data is unbalanced data, so I want to try type II or type III ANOVA. This is my data for your reference.

```
library(car)
#read data
input <- read.csv("input.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)

#This is my data for ANOVA
treatment   fraction    data
trt1    F45 -4.15E-05
trt1    F78 -7.24E-05
trt1    F45 -1.65E-05
trt1    F57 -2.22E-06
trt1    F78 -2.78E-05
trt1    F45 -5.13E-05
trt1    F57 -5.96E-05
trt1    F78 -4.09E-05
control F45 -4.42E-05
control F57 -1.11E-05
control F45 -2.73E-06
control F57 -9.02E-07
control F78 -6.37E-06
control F45 -4.70E-06
control F57 -2.73E-06

mod.1 <- lm( data ~ fraction * treatment, input )
Anova( mod.1, type=3 )
Anova( mod.1, type=2 )
```

Yes, some cells have only one replication, but I can run successfully in other data columns with the same operation, but it reports an error in this data column. I'm strange about this.

Any leads will be appreciated.
Mengying

Comment: Please edit your question so we can copy-paste it into R. Define `input` as the output of what `dput(input)` gives you, so we have the exact data you are working with.  Check that your code runs in a completely new console (which package does `Anova()` come from?). Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I have completed the information. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `car:::ANOVA.lm` function tests if the model's deviance (its residual sum of squares) is below a precision limit:

```
input <- read.table(text = "treatment   fraction    data
trt1    F45 -4.15E-05
trt1    F78 -7.24E-05
trt1    F45 -1.65E-05
trt1    F57 -2.22E-06
trt1    F78 -2.78E-05
trt1    F45 -5.13E-05
trt1    F57 -5.96E-05
trt1    F78 -4.09E-05
control F45 -4.42E-05
control F57 -1.11E-05
control F45 -2.73E-06
control F57 -9.02E-07
control F78 -6.37E-06
control F45 -4.70E-06
control F57 -2.73E-06", header = TRUE)

mod.1 <- lm( data ~ fraction * treatment, input )
Anova( mod.1, type=2 )
#Error in Anova.lm(mod.1, type = 2) : 
#  residual sum of squares is 0 (within rounding error)

deviance(mod.1) < sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)
#[1] TRUE
```

This test is probably done to avoid numeric issues due to floating point precision.

I suggest you simply rescale your dependent variable. This also rescales the residuals and the resulting sum of squares.

```
mod.2 <- lm( I(data * 1e6) ~ fraction * treatment, input )
library(car)
Anova( mod.2, type=2 )
#Anova Table (Type II tests)
#
#Response: I(data * 1e+06)
#                   Sum Sq Df F value  Pr(>F)  
#fraction            360.1  2  0.3605 0.70697  
#treatment          2375.6  1  4.7566 0.05709 .
#fraction:treatment  229.9  2  0.2302 0.79891  
#Residuals          4495.0  9                  
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice and immediate reply! I will take a try!

Comment: Roland beat me to it. This is precisely the right answer. Mengying, please consider upvoting it (click the little triangle point up next to the answer) and/or accepting it (click the little checkmark under the vote totals).